# does any scripture say valmiki's ramayana is the most authoritative among all Ramayanas?

Tags: ramayana, valmiki

wikipedia says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versions_of_Ramayana

"Ananda Ramayana is traditionally attributed to Valmiki. While it briefly recounts the traditional story of Rama, it is composed primarily of stories peripheral, though related, to Valmiki’s narrative. This ramayana provide information about last years of Rama's life. These include Ravana’s abduction of Sita and Rama’s installment of the Shiva Lingam at Rameswaram.[8]"

in particular,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ananda_Ramayana

"Ananda Ramayana is a Sanskrit text traditionally ascribed to the sage Valmiki, who is also credited with the Adbhuta Ramayana, Valmiki Ramayana, and the Yoga Vasishta (Vasishta Ramayana). The text has received little attention from scholars to date, though in some traditions it is considered one of the principles sources of Rama stories.[1]"

Comment: From where you took the last story?..In temple legend stories of Rameshwaram (a small book which I bought when I visited Rameshwaram), it was Sita who formed Linga of sand..

Comment: Among all the Ramayanas u mean?